# Rails 3 : Action Mailer issue render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have upgraded my app from rails 2.x to rails 3.2. I have used `render_message` method http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/render_message
but it is deprecated in rails 3.

Please suggest any alternate method for this. I already tried to use `template_name` but it was not worked. Please help

Answer (score 1):

It is deprecated in Rails 3, but [looking at the source](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionMailer/DeprecatedApi/render_message) reveals that the replacement for `render_message` is simply `render`. Source:

```
# File actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/deprecated_api.rb, line 123
def render_message(*args)
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "render_message is deprecated, use render instead", caller[0,2]
  render(*args)
end
```